# When calling a C++ function, how to skip several default parameters in uncertain positions？

Tags: c++, parameters

English is not my native language; please excuse some typing errors. Thanks.

I declare a class named `OLEDstream` with a constructor like:

```cpp
OLEDstream::OLEDstream( uint8_t        num, 
                        const uint8_t  *pins,
                        void           (*fAlarm)()  = NULL,
                        int            buffsz       = 21*5,
                        const uint8_t  *font        = u8g2_font_6x10_mr,
                        int            minx         = 0,
                        int            miny         = 11,
                        int            maxx         = 120,
                        int            maxy         = 60,
                        int            stepx        = 6,
                        int            stepy        = 11 );
```

In some cases, I'd like to change the value of `stepy`. However, skipping the middle default parameters is not allowed(as far as I know), so I have to pass all the parameters when calling it, even though I just want to change `stepy` from its default value.

Function overloading seems like a solution, but there are 8 default parameters and it's hard to predict which one users want to change. So I have to overload the function for 100+ times.

Are there some other suggestions, advice or programming skills for the situation?

Comment: Use the builder pattern? I'd have reached for it when the constructor hit 4 parameters.

Comment: Pass a struct. C++20 designated initializers make it look pretty: `func({.a = 10, .b = 20})`

Comment: "Function overloading seems like a solution, but there are 8 default parameters and it's hard to predict which one users want to change". A bigger problem is that you have multiple `int`s and when you omit one of them you cannot possibly tell which one is omitted. The function overloading method is just not viable. Solution is already given in the two previous comments.

Comment: Have you considered having a constructor with less parameters? Setup your class with default values, then have separate functions that modify other parameters.  As it is, there are way too many parameters in your constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You've written yourself into a corner with this many parameters. It's not allowed to "skip" default parameters indeed.

I recommend summing up all the parameters in `struct`s. This would allow specifying only some of the options while relying on the default member initializers for the rest.

```cpp
struct Vector { int x, y; };

struct Rectangle { Vector min, max; };

struct OLEDstreamOptions {
    uint8_t num;
    const uint8_t *pins;
    void (*fAlarm)() = nullptr;
    int buffsz = 21 * 5;
    const uint8_t *font = u8g2_font_6x10_mr;
    Rectangle bounds = {0, 11, 120, 60};
    Vector step = {6, 11};
};

// ...
OLEDstream(OLEDstreamOptions options) {
    use(options.step.x);
    // ...
}
```

Now, leaving some of the options defaulted is easy:

```cpp
auto stream = OLEDstream{{ .num = /* ... */, .pins = /* ... */, .step = {10, 20} }};
```

Comment: For info, that requires C++20.

Answer (score 0):

I am in agreement that too many parameters in the constructor will create problems. Nor do I disagree that the use of a struct will solve the problem.  I would just like to offer an alternative.  A `getter` can be given a default value.

I made a `getter/setter` combo for `minx` and `miny`.

Whether this is better than a struct, I will let others decide.

```
private:
   int minx = 0;     //private variable set to default
   int miny = 11;    //same here


public:
OLEDstream::OLEDstream( uint8_t        num, 
                        const uint8_t  *pins,
                        void           (*fAlarm)()  = NULL,
                        int            buffsz       = 21*5,
                        const uint8_t  *font        = u8g2_font_6x10_mr,
                        int            maxx         = 120,
                        int            maxy         = 60,
                        int            stepx        = 6,
                        int            stepy        = 11 );


   //getters and setters
   int OLEDstream::getMinx()
   {
      return minx;
   }

   void OLEDstream::setMinx(int myX)
   {
      minx = myX;
   }

   int OLEDstream::getMiny()
   {
      return miny;
   }

   void OLEDstream::setMiny(int myY)
   {
      miny = myY;
   }
```